# Combinar varias tablas y traer dos registros de una tabla especifica mysql

Tags: php, mysql

saludos a la comunidad, no suelo preguntar mucho, pero esta vez algo me esta dando un dolor de cabeza, soy principiante y tengo un problema, no pretendo me lo solucionen pero si me orienten que es una gran ayuda.

Veran tengo dos tablas **casos_caso y casos_seguimientos**, en la primera guardo datos basicos de los casos como la fecha de creacion un id de asunto y lo que se expone, en la segunda tabla siempre guardo 1 primer registro y en uno de los campos llamado origen le coloco, creacion del caso, y ademas de estatus abierto, tambien el id del usuario que lo creo y el id al usuario que se le asigno si puede resolver el caso, tambien comentarios que por ejemplo: el cliente llamo etc etc., ahora siempre esta este registro y ademas cuando cierran el caso se cambia el esatus a cerrado y ademas siempre conservo el usuario asignado y el id de quien lo cerro.

mi problema es a la hora de hacer los reportes, tengo un codigo todo feo:

```html
SELECT casos_caso.id, casos_caso.nivel, casos_caso.creado, clientes.identificacion, clientes.codigo_cliente, clientes.razonsocial, clientes.zona, asuntos_asunto.nombre as asunto, asuntos_asunto.id as idAsunto, estados.estado, municipios.municipio, casos_seguimiento.grupo_escalamiento, casos_seguimiento.cargo_se_asigno_caso, casos_seguimiento.id as idSeguimiento, casos_seguimiento.estatus, casos_seguimiento.origen, casos_seguimiento.creado as fechaSeguimiento, escalamientos.nombre, usuarios.usuario from casos_caso  JOIN clientes on casos_caso.id_cliente = clientes.id  JOIN asuntos_asunto on casos_caso.id_asunto = asuntos_asunto.id  JOIN estados on clientes.estado = estados.id JOIN municipios on clientes.municipio = municipios.id_municipio join casos_seguimiento on casos_caso.id = casos_seguimiento.id_caso JOIN escalamientos on casos_seguimiento.grupo_escalamiento = escalamientos.id JOIN usuarios on casos_seguimiento.id_usuario = usuarios.id
```

(perdon pero estaba un poco desesparado y de verdad estoy pasando de principiante con mysql y tengo algunos conocimientos sobre los join) que me trae todos los registros separados en cada linea si hay 5 comentarios este los trae todos pero solo me gustaria traiga solo el que diga creacion del caso y el que diga cerrado osea actualmente tengo 2 casos uno con 5 comentarios y otro con solo la creacion del caso, es posible alguna idea u orientcion donde salga solamente 2 lineas y de una vez traiga el id, el caso, creacion del caso, las dos fecha y los dos usuarios que lo creo y el que lo cerro, les dejo una tabla mas o menos como se deberia ver

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td class="text-left">Caso #</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Fecha Caso.</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Fecha Cierre.</td>

                    <td class="text-left">Razón Social/Nombre.</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Código.</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Rif/Cédula.</td>


                    <td class="text-left">Operador Creo el caso.</td>

                    <td class="text-left">Usuario Asignado.</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Usuario Cerró el caso.</td>
                    <td class="text-left">Estatus.</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

De ante muchas muchas gracias por la ayuda me puedan prestar. incluso mejorar la bd, o el codigo, de verdad muchas gracias

Comment: Pienso que a tu query le falta agregarles la sentencia WHERE para filtrar los registros que quieres obtener, ya que con tu consulta estas seleccionando todos los registros de las columnas que solicitas de esa union de tus tablas.

Comment: Si se lo agregue probe con: <pre>where casos_seguimiento.origen = 'Creación del Caso' or  casos_seguimiento.estatus = 'cerrado'</pre> reduje la cantidad de 5 a 3 registros pero quisiera que fueran solo  2 por lo meonso este caso, que poseo solo 2 casos en la bd pero de a poco encuentro la solucion